# python handling of its method parameters for datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I was practicing in python about datetime. For first function parameters passed, python treats as a tuple because of its bracket and first function fails but seconds works.

This function fails

```
from datetime import datetime, date
def epochConverter(a):
    mydate = datetime.date(a)
    return datetime(mydate).timestamp() 


epochConverter((2018,6,19,0,0,0))
```

but this works

```
def epochConverter2():
    return datetime(2018,6,19,0,0,0).timestamp()

print(epochConverter2())
```

Can somebody explain to me on this. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the tuple with `*` so you can pass the ints inside the tuple to the `datetime` function properly:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
def epochConverter(a):
    return datetime(*a).timestamp()
print(epochConverter((2018,6,19,0,0,0)))
```

Comment: Hey, that was my answer... ;)

Answer (score 1):

The argument `a` passed to `datetime.date(a)` in the first function is like calling `datetime.date()` with

```
datetime.date((2018,6,19,0,0,0))
```

This is a `tuple`. You can either unpack the tuple inside the function with

```
def epochConverter(a):
    return datetime(*a).timestamp()
```

(The conversion `mydate = datetime.date(a)` is not needed here.)

Or you need to pass all arguments separately with:

```
def epochConverter(Y, M, D, h, m, sec):
    return datetime(Y, M, D, h, m, sec).timestamp()

epochConverter(2018, 6, 19, 0, 0, 0)
```